# Problems with instance arguments in Agda

Tags: agda

I'm trying to follow the code for McBride's [*How to Keep Your Neighbours in Order*](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/Pivotal.pdf), and can't understand why Agda (I'm using Agda 2.4.2.2) gives the following error message:

> Instance search can only be used to find elements in a named type
>   when checking that the expression `t` has type `.T`

for function `_:-_` .  The code is given bellow

```
data Zero : Set where

record One : Set where
  constructor <>

data Two : Set where tt ff : Two

So : Two -> Set
So tt = One
So ff = Zero

record <<_>> (P : Set) : Set where
  constructor !
  field
    {{ prf }} : P

_=>_ : Set -> Set -> Set
P => T = {{ p : P }} -> T

infixr 3 _=>_

-- problem HERE!

_:-_ : forall {P T} -> << P >> -> (P => T) -> T
! :- t = t
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a recent email by Nils Anders Danielsson at the agda-dev mailing list precisely about this. I cannot find it online, so here is a quote:

> Conor uses lots of instance arguments in "How to Keep Your Neighbours
>   in Order". However, his code was written using the old variant of the
>   instance arguments, and fails to check now. I managed to make the code
>   work again using some small tweaks, and wonder if we could get away
>   with even less:
>
> I replaced
>
> ```
> record One : Set where constructor it
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> record One : Set where
>   instance
>     constructor it.
> ```
>
> This seems fine with me.
>
> I replaced
>
> ```
> _:-_ : forall {P T} -> <P P P> -> (P => T) -> T
> ! :- t = t
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> _:-_ : forall {P T} -> <P P P> -> (P => T) -> T
> ! {{prf = p}} :- t = t {{p = p}},
> ```
>
> because "Instance search can only be used to find elements in a
>   named   type". Similarly, in two cases I replaced a module parameter
>
> ```
> (L : REL P)
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> (L' : REL P) (let L = Named L'),
> ```
>
> where Named is a named type family:
>
> ```
> data Named {P : Set} (A : REL P) : REL P where
>   named : forall {x} -> A x -> Named A x
> ```