# Agda: How to infer proof of _≤_ (or, how to implement a binary search tree)

Tags: agda, dependent-type

I'm probably not going about this in the best way as Agda and, particularly, the Agda standard library are still very new to me.  I am trying to implement some notion of binary search trees.

I have a simple definition of a binary tree

```
data BTree (A : Set) : ℕ → Set where
  Leaf : A → BTree A 1
  Node : ∀ {n m} → A → BTree A n → BTree A m → BTree A (1 + n + m)
```

as well as two functions `bt-⊔ : ∀ {n : ℕ} → BTree ℕ n → ℕ` and `bt-⊓ : ∀ {n : ℕ} → BTree ℕ n → ℕ` which extract the maximum and minimum values from a binary tree.

I am now trying to define a data type which proves that a particular tree is a binary search tree.  Here's what I have so far.

```
data BST : {n : ℕ} → BTree ℕ n → Set where
  sortL : {x : ℕ} → BST (Leaf x)
  sortN : ∀ {n m} → {a : ℕ} → {l : BTree ℕ n} → {r : BTree ℕ m}
                            → (sl : BST l) → (sr : BST r)
                            → {cl : a ≥ (bt-⊔ l)} → {cr : a < (bt-⊓ r)}
                            → BST (Node a l r)
```

My intuition for the node BST constructor is to take the value stored at the node (`a`), the two subtrees (`l` and `r`), proofs that the two subtrees are BSTs (`sl` and `sr`) and proofs that the current value `a` is larger than everything in the left subtree and smaller than everything in the right (`cl` and `cr`).

This seems to more or less work, and I can construct the following simple tree and BST proof.

```
T₂ : BTree ℕ 3
T₂ = Node 5 (Leaf 3) (Leaf 7)

bst₂ : BST T₂
bst₂ = sortN sortL sortL {s≤s (s≤s (s≤s z≤n))} {s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s z≤n)))))}
```

However, I want to have Agda infer the proofs for `cl` and `cr` since they are extremely tedious.  If I don't specify them in the definition of `bst₂` then Agda seems to think I have holes in my code, giving me underscore variables related to `cl` and `cr`.

It's not clear to me how to go about this, nor that I'm even using this part of the standard library correctly.  I'm open to any suggestions or solutions which would make this easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the less-or-equal relation as a function:

```
open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Unit.Base using (⊤; tt)
open import Data.Nat.Base

_≤⊤_ : ℕ -> ℕ -> Set
0     ≤⊤ m     = ⊤
suc n ≤⊤ 0     = ⊥
suc n ≤⊤ suc m = n ≤⊤ m

test : 10 ≤⊤ 20
test = tt
```

And it's also possible to reify original proofs:

```
≤⊤→≤ : ∀ n m -> n ≤⊤ m -> n ≤ m
≤⊤→≤  0       m      _  = z≤n
≤⊤→≤ (suc n)  0      ()
≤⊤→≤ (suc n) (suc m) p  = s≤s (≤⊤→≤ n m p)

test-test : 10 ≤ 20
test-test = ≤⊤→≤ _ _ test
```

`test-test` evaluates to `s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s (s≤s z≤n)))))))))`.

> as well as two functions `bt-⊔ : ∀ {n : ℕ} → BTree ℕ n → ℕ` and `bt-⊓ : ∀
>   {n : ℕ} → BTree ℕ n → ℕ` which extract the maximum and minimum values
>   from a binary tree.

It's better to store them rather than extract. Check the [How to Keep Your Neighbours in Order](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Pivotal.pdf) paper which in great details explains how to define ordered data types (the code in the paper doesn't type check with recent versions of Agda, see some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29023160/3237465)).

> However, I want to have Agda infer the proofs for `cl` and `cr` since they
>   are extremely tedious.

These `sortN` and `sortL` are tedious too. It should be possible to define

```
open import Relation.Nullary

ordered? : ∀ {n} -> (b : BTree ℕ n) -> Dec (BST b)
ordered? = ...
```

`ordered?` decides whether a tree is ordered or not. Then you can eliminate this `Dec` with the help from `Relation.Nullary.Decidable.from-yes`. But read the paper first and choose a more suitable representation of `BST`.

Comment: Thanks for the general advice and the link to that paper.  It should, at a minimum, give me a lot more things to try.